# How to use more than 1 Youtube Video in same activity

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

i am creating an app and recently i had used youtube API to implement videos in my application in an activity but 1 video is working fine but i just coudn't figure out how to use more than 1 video in the same activity.The below is the code using which i am using for a single video.

```
public class how2Videos extends YouTubeBaseActivity{
public static final String API_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
public static final String VideoTitanium = "ySQoAiWPXHE";
public static final String VideoNandroid = "36cihz4l-vk";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_how2_videos);

    /** Initializing YouTube player view **/
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.Youtube);
    youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, "ySQoAiWPXHE" );


}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
    /** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
    /** Start buffering **/
    if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VideoTitanium);
    }
}


@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize Your Video.Check if you have a proper internet!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

As i am a beginner here so i kindly expect a bit brief answer,thank you.

Comment: Do you want both videos to have their own players within an activity, or just queue the videos?

Comment: I want both videos to have their own players with in an activity @RishabhTatiraju

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion @cricket_007 i won't add them again..

Comment: You could try using fragments to display each video. Have a fragment for each video you wish to display. Or, as a last resort you can set two webviews and use the YouTube embed code to display the videos, without using the API.

Comment: I am not so goof at fragments so can you please give me some example code or a proper guide to do so and i don't want to use a webview since it is not user friendly and also dosen't support full screen..thank you@RishabhTatiraju

Comment: There are tons of examples in StackOverflow. Have a look at them. You can also check this out http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~campbell/cs65/lecture09/lecture09.html